# How to force LD to link a PIC assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm, ld

So I want to assemble this very simple code:

```
extern printf

Segment .data
string: 
    db "foo", 0

Segment .text
extern printf


global main
main:

    push rbp
    xor rax, rax
    mov rdi, string

    call printf 
    pop rbp
    ret
```

but I wanted to make it a PIE so I changed

> mov rdi, string

to

> lea rdi, [rel+string]

but after doing that I get the following errors from ld/gcc:

> **relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `printf@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not**
>   **be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/bin/ld:**
>   **final link failed: bad value**

I'm compiling and assembling this with:
*nasm -f elf64 bar.s -o bar.o; gcc -fPIC bar.o -o bar*

Why am  I getting this error? It compiles just fine with the -no-pie flag

Comment: LD doesn't automatically create PLT stubs and rewrite your call instructions when linking an ELF shared object (including PIE executables).  You need `call printf@plt` or `call [rel printf@GOTPCREL]`.  See [How can I call printf normally in assembly without @PLT but just call printf with -l option in gcc with standard library,](//stackoverflow.com/q/56404855) for the opposite question.  Also see [What does @plt mean here?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5469274)

Comment: Oops, `call [rel printf wrt ..got]` is the NASM syntax for gcc `-fno-plt` style code-gen that uses early-binding for dynamic linker symbols, and `call printf wrt ..plt` is NASM for explicit PLT style.  `call printf@plt` is GAS syntax.

Comment: Ciro's answer on [How to print a number in assembly NASM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/32853546) explains exactly what you need to call printf from a PIE or non-PIE executable in NASM.

Comment: Also found a better duplicate which goes into the details of PLT vs. GOTPCREL and PIE vs. non-PIE.  [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](//stackoverflow.com/q/52126328)

Comment: @PeterCordes forgive my ignorance but what does *wrt* stand for? Also GOTPCREL is, I assume, the GOT right?

Comment: WRT = With Respect To.  GOTPCREL is a PC-relative way of addressing the GOT.

Comment: Updated my answer on the linked duplicate with a bit more detail on those.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks Peter. Here's what happened now, your version which uses `jmp WRT ..puts` worked but it segfaulted after showing the message. I couldn't assemble the one which uses **..GOTPCREL** because apparently the symbol is undefined.

Comment: You want `call` instead of `jmp` because you're not making a tailcall.

Comment: Apparently `..GOTPCREL` only works in YASM, not NASM.  In NASM, use `call [rel printf wrt ..got]`.  (You only need the `rel` keyword if you leave out `default rel`, but yeah, `..got` instead of `..gotpcrel`)  I'll update my YASM answer for that after lunch.

Comment: @PeterCordes it worked! just one more thing, I changed **call** to **jmp** just to see what happens and it worked as well, so can I use  them interchangeably?

Comment: `call` pushes a return address.  `jmp` doesn't.  That's the only difference, but it's a pretty key difference!!  Use `jmp foo` to a new function instead of `call foo` / `ret`.  If you need to do *anything* between the call and ret (like `pop rbp`), you can't just replace call/ret with jmp.  (You'd have to make other changes like doing the `pop rbp` first to make an optimized tailcall).  Plus you have `int main`, not `void foo`. I updated my answer on the linked duplicate to work for NASM as well, and to take out the tailcall optimization from the example because it's a totally separate issue.